# Extract specific values from HTML table using regex

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a html file that contains this table row:

```
<tr> 
<td class="color21 right" style="font-size:12px; line-height:1.2;">&nbsp;Location</td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;">10</td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;"><img src="../../icons/9.gif" alt="Type" />     </td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;">3</td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;">7</td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;"><img src="../../icons/11.gif" alt="Type" />    </td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;">3</td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;">10</td>
<td class="color21" style="font-size:12px;"><img src="../../icons/9.gif" alt="Type" />    </td>
</tr>
```

I'm retrieving file contents using file_get_contents.

How can I extract all TD values using preg_match, preg_match_all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**DomParser**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php&ei=l2JNU9_2IIyCrgfvPg&usg=AFQjCNFJNfLdZUU8vzpWShOyVbSgsLReDQ&bvm=bv.64764171,d.bmk) to Parse the html content regex are not reliable on this cases.

```
    $str=file_get_contents('read.txt');
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($str);
    $tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach($tr as $td)
  {
    if(!empty($td->nodeValue)){
        echo $td->nodeValue."\n";
    }else{
        $images=$td->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($images as $image){
            echo $image->getAttribute('src')." ";
            echo $image->getAttribute('alt');
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works great for numeric values, but I also need image values such as 9.gif, 11.gif... Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I would be satisfied to get whole img string along with numerical values <img src="../../icons/9.gif" alt="Type" />

Comment: @mpet i have edited my answer to get the img src along with the values.

Answer (score 1):

Think over if you really wanna a regex to parse html

But you can use this:

```
<td.+?>(.+?)</td>
```

The first group will contain the values of `<td>`

Comment: What do you suggest instead?